# ORA 600 and 7445 after upgrade from 18 to 19C

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, oracle-18c

I'm getting errors ORA 600 and 7445 in alert log after upgrading Oracle from 18 to 19C, the error mostly occurs on merge statements, below is the error message:

```
Errors in file /db1/oracle/diag/rdbms/STGDB/STGDB2/trace/STGDB2_ora_268833.trc  (incident=368790):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17147], [0x7FED269BFEB0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-03135: connection lost contact
```

I did some search so I have disabled online stats gathering:

```
alter session set "_optimizer_gather_stats_on_load" = false;
```

The other workaround is to edit application codes to add hints to the merge statements, but this action is very time-consuming and requires the dev team to edit the queries.

```
/*+ NO_GATHER_OPTIMIZER_STATISTICS */
```

Also, I tried setting "_optimizer_gather_stats_on_load" = false on system-level, but still have the same issue, moreover, I have installed two patches but still getting the same error.
Does anyone have the same issue? any workaround?

Comment: I think including the actual error messages, verbatim, as text and not pictures, would be helpful.

Comment: I have included the exact error message

Answer (score 1):

ora-0600 is, by definition, an 'unhandled exception'.  AKA, "you hit a bug"  It is an umbrella error code that can mean just about anything.  The only real resolution is to open an service request with Oracle Support.

Before actually opening an SR, you can search My Oracle Support for 'ora-0600', which will lead you to a lookup tool where you can provide the specific version of Oracle, along with the additional arguments listed in the error message.  That will bring up any support notes dealing with the specifics of your error.

Of course, access to My Oracle Support and the ability to open an SR presupposes that you have a paid support account.

Comment: I agree with @EdStevens. These are internal errors that can only truly be resolved by Oracle Support. They very well may require specific patches. You will not find definitive answers on this forum.